# Malformed calls from JS : field sizes are different [[8,39],[4,0]

Tags: android, react-native, react-hooks, android-permissions, react-native-contacts

I want to display the list of contacts on my AVD but Im facing an error (I tried linking the package but it did nothing):

#### My code :

```
    const [contact, setContact] = useState([]);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
        {
          'title': 'Contacts',
          'message': 'This app would like to view your contacts.'
        }
      ).then(() => {
        Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
          if (err === 'denied'){
            // error
          } else {
            // contacts returned in Array
            setContact(contacts);
            console.log(contact);
          }
        })
      })
      .catch((err)=> {
          console.log(err);
      })
    }, []);
```

#### The error :

[image]

I searched everywhere for a solution but there's nothing about this issue, thanks for helping me by advance.

Comment: what you are getting in contact

Comment: I'm getting nothing, the only thing that display is the error even if I console.log() nothing shown in the console

Comment: After clearing cache and retarting the emulator I got this error on the console :
```[Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.

[[8,39],[4,0],[[36,2000,1607543301566,false]],1583]]```

Comment: In my case, I was not updating an array state correctly, checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-react-js

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The APIs has been updated in version 6. Changing from callback (version 5 uses callback) to promise worked for me. I mean change -

```js
Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => { });
```

to -

```js
Contacts.getAll()
    .then((contacts) => {
      // work with contacts
    })
    .catch((e) => { //handle error })
```

Comment: Not the code which was the problem but the library, the code worked well and the question is now answered and solved

Comment: This not an issue with the lib as the documentation clearly mentions this usage. Also you can check out the typing for the getAll method. https://github.com/morenoh149/react-native-contacts/blob/master/index.d.ts

Comment: They have changed the apis from version 5 to 6 which was causing the issue.

Comment: It is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

With the updated API version, you need to change the callback syntax to promise .then and .catch such as

```
Contacts.getAll()
    .then(contacts => { //your code here })
    .catch(e => { //handle error })
```